# jquery script with list.pagination.js not processing after changing page

Tags: jquery

```
<div id='listId'>
<ul class='list'>
<li class='add_to_email' email='a@gmail.com'>a@gmail.com</li>
<li class='add_to_email' email='b@gmail.com'>b@gmail.com</li>
<li class='add_to_email' email='c@gmail.com'>c@gmail.com</li>
<li class='add_to_email' email='d@gmail.com'>d@gmail.com</li>
<li class='add_to_email' email='e@gmail.com'>e@gmail.com</li>
</ul>
<ul class='pagination'></ul>
</div>
<input type='text' id='show_what_was_clicked'>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        valueNames: [ 'email' ],
        page: 3,
        plugins: [
            ListPagination({})
        ]
    };
    var listObj = new List('listId', options);

    $(".add_to_email").click(function(){
        $("#show_what_was_clicked").val($(this).attr("email"));
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2tkwr5mz/2/

Have a list that loads in list.js, can't get the click event to fire after switching to page 2. If I go back to page 1, it still fires. (Displays email when clicked, but only on page 1.)

Answer (score 0):

Just used click instead of ready.

```
$("#expand_group").click(function(){
```